# jquery mouseenter is not working on div named "main"

Tags: jquery

in javascript color is changed but when i apply jQuery it's not working anymore

```
 var main = $("#main");
    main.on("mouseenter",  function () {
        main.style = "background-color: #99999 ;";
    });
    main.on("mouseleave", function () {
        main.style = "";
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `main` is not a DOM element - it is a jQuery object, so you can use jQuery's `css` method like this:

```
var main = $("#main");
main.on("mouseenter",  function () {
    main.css("background-color", "#99999");
});
main.on("mouseleave", function () {
    main.css("background-color", "transparent");
});
```

Comment: it's working on Microsoft Edge but not in Google Chrome

Comment: alright, but it has to reflect same result in every browser

Comment: @SaroashCh - it does, you said it specifically didn't work in Chrome. I have made the background color more obvious in the sample page to show that it works (as the sample page is grey, and your background color is also kinda grey).

Comment: there is another fault , when i run in iss express this code not working but when i run app direct it works , in visual studio 2015

Comment: For the record, I agree entirely with this answer, and I believe it is the best way to change the background colour of an element.  But, if for some reason a user wants to change the *style* attribute, you use the syntax `main.attr('style','background-color: #99999');`